# Make software to change its behavior as per the version selection

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, client-server

I have a software that acts like a server. The clients communicate with this software through exposed interfaces. Our company wants to introduce new features to our software.

Version 1:
 Client <---> Interface X1, Y1, Z1 <----> Server

Version 2:

Client <---> Interface X2, Y2, Z2 ----> Server

Clients want the capability of switching to older version whenever they desire. Of course they will change their interface to the older version if they want to switch to a different server version. Our company wants us to have a drop down to select different versions. Selecting the latest version should expose new features. Selecting previous version should hide the new features. Now, the problem is that the new features modify the existing features' behaviors also! Some of the exposed interfaces have been changed. This includes existing method signatures changes, some method deletions and some new method additions. But not major code changes within an existing method have been done. The client software will undergo changes to adapt to the server changes whenever they switch the versions. Our server code maintenance is the main concern as the code base is pretty big. So our company neither wants us to add if/else condition checks to achieve this goal nor code duplication. The software has been written in C# using.NET 3.5 & WCF. The clients communicate with this software using SOAP.

Please suggest me the best approach to achieve this goal. Any document/design/code I can refer is also appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060.aspx) is a good starting point in wcf service guidelines. WCF developers kept in mind versioning while developing, so most of the problems are known and described in the wcf documentations

If you contracts are changeable, and you can't do something with this, well you can keep old interfaces and implement new ones

Assume you have contract

```
interface IContractV1
{
   void M();
   void N();
}
```

Now in your second version, you want to remove one method, and add another

```
interface IContractV2
{
   void M();
   void P();
}
```

Your service can keep both contracts up, with different URIs

```
youraddress/service/v1
youraddress/service/v2
```

And now old client can connect to the old service and new one to the new service

Note that you can re-use datacontracts, as described in guidelines, but again you can't remove any property from there too

Comment: Thanks ArsenMkrt for your guidance. To delve into more detail, the contract - interfaces are given by third party. It is kind of a standard that all the companies should follow. So we do not have control over the interfaces. We need to implement and support them. Is there any way I can conform to both versions of interfaces without too many changes?

Comment: what is the problem of keeping both contracts? you can have two interfaces in that case and keep implementations for both cases, it will not necessarily bring code repeat, you can implement it in one service or have some helper classes

Comment: Thank you for understanding my problem. Could you eloberate a bit more? Since I have not done too much of design stuff I would really appreciate if you could give some example or point to a place where I can check it out?

Comment: I edited a post a bit, hope this make sense, please specify which part is a question for you I will try to answer more clear